# Have any organisations said they will definitely benefit from a no-deal Brexit?

Tags: brexit

From what I understand, the 'deal' being discussed by Parliament is less a trade deal more a list of what standards will or will not be recognised and what processes will or will not be followed after the United Kingdom leaves the European Union.  This ranges from how Customs checks will handled to whether or not organic producers in the UK will be recognised in the EU after Brexit.  It also affect employment and travel rights and whether or not qualifications are recognised by either side, among other things.

Many people, both in Government and in the public are strongly advocating that the UK leaves the EU without this deal. Again, from what I understand, this would mean that qualifications and standards are no longer mutually recognised, there would be increased customs checks and there would be more difficulty employing staff from the EU.

On the back of the difficulties that may be raised by a no-deal Brexit, coupled with the uncertainty of a change from the status quo to a globally unprecedented situation, many organisations and companies have stated that they will be negatively affected.  There are also reports from many government departments stating that a no-deal Brexit will have a detrimental effect on the UK as a whole.

My question is, **have any organisations stated, unequivocally, that they will benefit from a no-deal Brexit?**

By organisation I mean company, trade body or government department.  Any statement made by the organisation should be backed up by figures.  I would prefer to see statements along the lines of 'in the event of no-deal we will do *x* which will increase\decrease *y* by *z* amount thus benefiting us'.  I am primarily interested in UK organisations, with them having the most to gain from no-deal however I would like to see an international perspective.

I have tried to keep the tone of this question politically neutral.  It is not a question about the benefits or consequences of a no-deal Brexit, simply whether or not anybody has stated that they *will* be better off in that event.

Comment: Somerset Capital Management? https://ftalphaville.ft.com/2018/02/08/2198570/jacob-rees-moggs-huge-personal-windfall-after-brexit/ Quite sarcastic in tone...

Comment: It is quite common to see people in threads claim that they run a business and it will be unaffected or do even better under Brexit although that's not exactly citable.  As far as government departments go it depends on what you mean by better.  If having a bigger budget, more staff and more work is better then there are a lot of them.  Most obviously the Department For Exiting the EU which presumably wouldn't even exist.

Answer (score 5):

There were [German news reports](https://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/handel-konsumgueter/umsatzsteigerung-aldi-und-lidl-profitieren-vom-brexit/21195934.html) that discount stores like aldi and lidl are due to benefit with their UK operations since more workers would be in low-wage jobs and forced to watch their expenses. In April 2018 they quoted the analyst Planer:

> „Aldi und Lidl werden profitieren, wenn in Großbritannien künftig mehr Verbraucher beim Einkauf auf den Preis achten müssen.“
>
> "Aldi and Lidl will profit if more consumers in Great Britain have to be price-conscious while shopping." (my translation)

Of course there is nothing "definitely" about these news reports. Journalists and analysts are guessing.

Comment: As of now, two upvotes, one downvote and no comment. I wonder if that was dislike of the quality of my answer or dislike of the content of the news.

Comment: @Thunderforge, edited, but it is a short article and I won't quote it in full -- I respect their need to get advertising revenue from their own site ...

Comment: This is the opinion of a writer not a statement from Aldi or Lidl so, while interesting, it doesn't answer the specific question asked. We'd need a direct quote from Aldi or Lidl for that.  Note that I think Aldi and Lidl may be hit harder by Brexit due to the amount of imported goods they sell.  Obviously all retailers import goods to some extent but I think Aldi and Lidl have a higher percentage than say Tesco.  It is possible that all supermarkets will suffer under Brexit but the cheaper end of the market will suffer less.  I'm not sure that would count as 'benefit' as per the question.

Comment: The short quote you have now works for me. Thank you for making that change!